# Text Classification - DNN

Tags: nlp, tensorflow2.0

I am performing text classification using a Deep Neural network. My problem is that I am receiving high accuracy 98 on train data whereas my validation accuracy is 49.

I have tried the following:

1. Shuffled the data
2. My train and validation data is 80:20 split
3. I am using 100 dimensions Glov vector

Any suggestions?

```py
def get_Model():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size+1, embedding_dim, input_length=max_length, weights= . [embeddings_matrix], trainable=False),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')
    ])
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer="adam",metrics=['acc'])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model is clearly overfitting. Standard tricks to prevent overfitting are:

- Adding dropout,
- L2 regularization,
- Trying a smaller model.

It is rather unusual to use convolutions and LSTMs at the same time (although it is perfectly fine). Perhaps keeping only one of them is the best way to make the network smaller.

My guess is that you are working with a rather small dataset. Having a bigger dataset also helps to prevent overfitting but it is not usually a piece of applicable advice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems there was a problem with data labeling.  Due to which, validation accuracy was getting impacted